# CSS menu - main option makes wider when submenu appears - how to fix it?

Tags: css, menu, hover

This is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/e92Dj/17/

The problem is - main `<li>` becomes wider, because `<ul>` inside has more text.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ul#mainmenu > li:hover > ul
{
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e92Dj/22/

Answer (score 0):

This may be an good-enough solution for you:

```
ul#mainmenu > li
{   
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;    

    width:50px;
}

ul#mainmenu > li > ul 
{
    display: none;      
    margin-left:-40px;
    width:200px;
}
```

and your jsFiddle :
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e92Dj/19/)

Comment: Thanks, it helped, but I prefer Naynana way of doing this (answer above/below).